# I can't show the tether (USDT) symbol, ₮, in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to show the tether symbol, ₮, inside Text. In iOS, it's correct, but I have a problem with Android. It just shows a rectangle.

```
Text("₮"),
```

I also tried \u20AE:

```
 Text("\u20AE"),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all font family compatible with Tether symbol. You can try '**Roboto**' for Android usually has support for this symbol.

```
Text(
  "\u20AE",
  style: TextStyle(
    fontFamily: 'Roboto', // Use the default font
  ),
),
```